# Filter a RDD from a specific character list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to generate statistic from a password dictionary "data". 
Result:

```
data_pass_week.count()
data_pass_medium.count()
data_pass_hard.count()
```

I have to check the characters of every word in the dictionary.
For example I would like to put in data_pass_medium, all the words containing specials characters, but it doesn't work.
I think I made a lot of mistakes. Can you help me, please?

```
scala> val data = sc.textFile("folder.txt")
scala> val specialChars = List('*', '@', '&', '=', '#', '?', '!', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>')
val data2 = data.filter(ligne => for (i <- 0 to specialChars.size) ligne.contains(specialChars(i)))
```

Result:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:388)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:387)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:387)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:27)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:27)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: `data.filter(line => specialChars.exists(char => line.contains(char)))` should work. However, the error seems more related to binary incompatibilities, make sure you are using correct versions of **Spark**, **Scala** & **JRE**, both for _compile_ and for _runtime_.

Comment: This produces the same error :(. I'm going to search around the compatibility problem.